# Using nginx as reverse Proxy and blocking any HTTP requests

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using nginx as reverse proxy for my flask API. When I make a http request I still receive the API response , whereas of my understanding I should receive an 400 error.

I have tried all the things I could find for that topic, but I couldn't get it working properly. I just replaced the redirect with the return code.

for example I used this guide
https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx

**default file**

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        return 400;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name _;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
        ssl on;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH: !aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        location / {
            # reverse proxy and serve the app # running on the localhost: 8000 proxy_pass http: //127.0.0.1:8000/;
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

The result should be that when you make a http request you should get an error and when you make a https request you should get the JSON respond.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `ssl on;` directive

`ssl` flag in `listen` will handle it.

You can also check http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server

Comment: sorry for answering so late, but I had other problems to solve first. I tried that, but I was still able to get a 200 answer from http. Any idea how to prevent that?